# How add Content-Transfer-Encoding to requests files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to send requests with files using requests lib (or other, if it's impossible). For example:

```
request = requests.post('url', 
                        files={'data': (None, name, 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8')})
```

here

```
None is file
name is name
"text/plain; charset=UTF-8" is Content-Type
```

and i need add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` to this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate? What did you try? What happened?

Comment: Are you trying to send headers?

Comment: `requests` should set an appropriate Content-Transfer-Encoding automatically.  Why do you need it set to a specific value?

Comment: @jwodder, because i get error, if `Content-Transfer-Encoding` != binary

Comment: @Pavel, i want to send simular requests: https://pastebin.com/KNz4033J